# Go + Windows API

Tags: golang

Работа с реестром, устройствами, winapi, итд
Реализовано ли это и насколько данный язык подходит для подобных задач?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все сделать можно. Вам нужна только обвязка для апи. Ее можно либо написать самостоятельно, либо взять готовую - к примеру тут [AllenDang/w32](https://github.com/AllenDang/w32). Там правда не все винапи, но ведь никто не мешает дописать для нужных - там не сложно. С реестром работают через winapi и в приведенной выше библиотеке такое есть в [advapi](https://github.com/AllenDang/w32/blob/c92a5d7c8fed59d96a94905c1a4070fdb79478c9/advapi32.go).

Работа с устройствами - тут сложнее. Устройства бывают разные и не совсемы просто так можно работать. И тем более написать универсальную библиотеку для них. Но с многими вполне можно. Например, банальный старый вопрос, как работать с COM портом. А точно также как и в других языках - открывать как файл и читать.

А вот подходит ли GO для подобного - сложный вопрос. Для специалистов в принципе побоку, на чем писать. Но как по мне, то работа с апи - это больше все таки к обычному c/c++ - там и документации больше, и примеров. А на GO придется постоянно как не враппер дописывать, так разбираться, как именно правильно пробросить структуры.